# Get wordpress thumbnail via RSS with fetch_feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I'm triyng to fetch the thumbnail from a wordpress rss article via fetch_feed but I can't find a way work with the array the RSS send me.

Example:

1 - From print_r feed I have this

```
[xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) ) [http://webnus.net/rss/mec/] => Array ( [startDate] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => 2022-01-17 [attribs] => Array ( )
```

I can call it with this:

```
echo $item->get_item_tags('http://webnus.net/rss/mec/','startDate')[0]['data'];
```

How can I get the url of the image from here:

```
[xml_base] => [xml_base_explicit] => [xml_lang] => ) ) ) [http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/] => Array ( [content] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => [attribs] => Array ( [] => Array ( [medium] => image [url] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/image.jpg [width] => 648 [height] => 430 ) )
```

I tried everything... without success..
The method I'm using is this one:

```
/* include the required file */     include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
/* specify the source feed   */     $rss = fetch_feed('URL OF THE FEED');
/* disable order by date     */     $rss->enable_order_by_date(false);
/* checks obj. is created    */     if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :
/* specify number of items   */       $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(4);
/* create an array of items  */       $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
                                    endif;

if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<div><h4>No contents</h4></div>';
      else
      // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
      foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :
?>

<h4 style="margin-bottom:3px;"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></h4>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i'm here just to up the thread, problem same to me